# create lists dynamically inside loops

Tags: c#, list, dynamic

How can I create lists dynamically inside loops

say, I have a list of name

like this:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();

name.add("name1");

name.add("name2");

name.add("name3");
```

I would like to have Lists from above list (names)

Like

```
List<string> name1 = new List<string>();

List<string> name2 = new List<string>();

List<string> name3 = new List<string>();
```

really appreciate it

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Wouldn't a [**Dictionary<TKey, TValue>**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) be better for this purpose?

Comment: Or maybe a nested [**Tuple**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) if nesting goes even beyond (a list of lists of lists, for example)

Comment: of course that there is an error, `t.ToString()` is of type _string_, while the list initializator expects an `IEnumerable<string>`, like `new[] {"a", "b", "c"}` - **Edited** There was a comment of the author of the question asking for a specific issue on a sample code

Comment: your not really making sense.... why cant you just create a list in the loop. you need to give more code... so we can try and work out what you are trying to achieve.